# When is a homomorphism between two group presentations an isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

Because this is an assignment for a class I'm taking I won't specify the groups, but I will abstract the question a little bit since I can't find an answer to this online or in my recommended text.

I have two groups on two generators each with a single relation, say $\langle\ a,b\ |\ r_1\ \rangle$ and $\langle\ x,y\ |\ r_2\  \rangle$. I have defined a homomorphism between these two groups that sends the relation $r_1$ to $r_2$, but I'm struggling to show that this is injective and surjective. Is there a common method to solving this sort of problem?

(Edit: The homomorpism is defined by sending a word $w=w_1\cdots w_n$ to $\eta(w)=\eta(w_1)\cdots\eta(w_n)$)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a standard method: you construct a homomorphism $\phi:\langle a,b \ | \ r_1 \rangle \to \langle x,y \ | \ r_2 \rangle$ by defining words $\phi(a), \phi(b)$ in $x$ and $y$ such that their images in the second group satisfy the relation $r_1$, and likewise you construct $\psi:\langle x,y \ | \ r_2 \rangle \to \langle a,b \ | \ r_1 \rangle$ by defining words $\psi(x), \psi(y)$ in the letters $a,b$ such that their images in the first group satisfy the relation $r_2$.

Then you check that $\phi(\psi(x))=x, \phi(\psi(y))=y, \psi(\phi(a))=a$, and $\psi(\phi(b))=b$.

There is nothing more that can be said without knowing more about the particular example. This can be quite involved in certain cases.

Comment: Right, of course! I'm just so used to showing that a homomorphism is bijective that I'd overlooked something like this - thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!